# CodeChef “Double Strings” Wrong Answer

Tags: python

My code gives the wrong answer (according to the judge) and I'm unable to figure out why (the second code). I just started solving the easy set of questions on CodeChef a couple of days ago.

A Double string is one where the first half is equal to the second half (length of string is even). The problem statement was to find out the max possible number of characters that can be obtained by removing and changing the order of symbols of a palindrome of length N.

The first line of the sample input contains an integer T - the number of test cases. Then, T lines follow. Each line consists of a single integer N - the length of a palindrome.

Obviously, if the palindrome is of even length, the length of the double string will be N. If the palindrome is of odd length, then the output should be N-1.

This is also evident from one of my accepted solutions as given below:

```
def main():
    t = int(raw_input())
    for i in xrange(t):
        n = int(raw_input())
        if n%2:
            print (n-1)
        else:
            print n
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

What I am unable to figure out is why my other solution (below) is rejected with the reason being Wrong Answer even though it does the same thing (according to me). Is there any case where it gives a different output from the code above?

[Link to the problem statement](http://www.codechef.com/problems/DOUBLE)

```
def main():
    t = int(raw_input())
    for i in xrange(t):
        n = raw_input()
        if n[-1] in '02468':
            print int(n)
        else:
            print (int(n)-1)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your odd/even check is wrong because `raw_input()` can return number surrounded by spaces.

```
>>> n = raw_input()
12  
>>> n
'12  '
>>> n[-1] in '02468'
False
>>> int(n) % 2 == 0
True
```

As you see, accepted solution can handle input with spaces and you solution can't.

To fix it, use `n = raw_input().strip()`

Note that in real Python programming, you should always use `int(n) % 2` check, because it is straightforward, efficient and will not accept wrong input such as `'abc22'`.

Comment: Thanks, adding the `strip` had it accept my solution. The problem specs said 'Each line consists of a single integer N - the length of a palindrome.' which led me to mistakenly believe it had only the integer without any extra characters.